# connect Jenkins to Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: jenkins

How can I connect Jenkins to Microsoft SQL Server?

I would like to run a script using Jenkins to update some tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you really want to do. If you just want to run a script which connects to the DB and executes the queries using the command line client, you can use the existing "execute shell / batch" build step, or some of the plugins:

- [ssh plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) - remotely execute a script
- [x-shell plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XShell+Plugin) - makes it easier to integrate scripts for cross-platform envs

You could also try and build your own starting from the basics, [Jenkins library plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Libraryplugins)

Comment: I just want to do you said. I tried the possibility of use "execute batch" and when I build the job, I get an error that says Jenkins doens't find jdbc driver... I placed the .jar in different folders (I'm not completely sure where it must be) and it still doesn't work. Would you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: The thing I want to do is launch a SoapUI project which connects to the database. But when I build it, Jenkins give an error that it can't find the driver jdbc. For that reason I was thinking about connect directly Jenkins to database and remove that part from the SoapUI project.

Comment: Anyway I will try your choice during the week

Comment: I think you should pursue the orignal problem and make sure you have correctly configured the SoapUi installation and that it has the MSSql driver available

Comment: Since you get an error I'd say there's something different in the classpath when running from Jenkins. Perhaps you should change your question and show your jenkins config and the stacktrace you get when running

Comment: You are totally right! I'm going to create another questiong because your previous answer are really useful :)